# Общественная и научная экспертиза или экспертизы?

Tags: число, согласование, лексика

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться. Если можно, то с обоснованием.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Общественная и научная* ***экспертиза***.
В данном случае под словом экспертиза понимается некая комплексная проверка, по нескольким непересекающимся направлениям, какого-то важного и сложного проекта. Однако все отдельные усилия различных групп экспертов сливаются для постороннего внешнего наблюдателя в одну большую, кем-то скоординированную работу. Так что ед. число вполне обоснованно.

Comment: Спасибо! Понятно.